# How can I create multiple connections in a molecule using the chemfig usepackage?

Tags: chemfig

Dear fellow Tex users,

I would like to draw some complex molecules using the chemfig package and am facing a problem when wishing to make several independent connections between atoms in my molecule. I wanted to use the ? as a connection option, but it seems, that this only works for connections sharing a central atom. How can I make more than one connections?

My example code (below) gives me the output depicted in the picture.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*7(A-B(-)(-[::5]H(-)(-[:120]K)-[::35]I-[::35]J?)-C?-D-E(-[::-20])(-[::260])-F-G-)}
\end{document}
```

[image: output generated from the source code given]

I would now like to also connect node K with both node I and node D. How can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance for any help on this problem!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although not completely relevant for this document, but post an example that runs 'out of the box', i.e. specifiy the documentclass, such that other users don't need to add it manually

Comment: Thank you, I just added the information on documentclass.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem and I wanted to share it with you. 
The `chemfig` package also allows you to set "anchors" by adding a name for the anchor in brackets. In my example below I set one anchor for closing the connection from `C` to `J` and another for the connection from `K` to `I` and `D`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemname{%
   \chemfig{*7(A-B(-)(-[::5]H(-)(-[:120]K?[upper])-[::35]I?[upper]-[::35]J?[ring])-C?[ring]-D?[upper]-E(-[::-20])(-[::260])-F-G-)}
}%
{longicyclene}
\par 
\end{document}
```

[image: output]